# Intersection and Sum of Subspaces

Tags: vector-spaces

I just woke up this and I was extremely curious if there were any subspaces of a vector space such that $X\cap (Y + Z) \neq (X \cap Y) + (X \cap Z)$?

---

Just a curious person. Thanks in advances.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in $\mathbb R^2$:

Take $X=[x=y], Y=[y=0], Z=[x=0]$.

Then $X\cap (Y + Z) = X$, but $(X \cap Y)=(X \cap Z)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are such $X,Y,Z$ : take $Y=Vect\{(1,0)\}$ (one-dimensional set generated by (1,0)), $Z=Vect\{(0,1)\}$ and $X=Vect\{(1,1)\}$ ; then $X \cap (Y+Z)=X \cap R^2=Vect\{(1,1)\}$ whereas $X \cap Y + X\cap Z=\{0\}+\{0\}=\{0\}$.